# Is there a way to use an extra test database for my java tests using intellj?

Tags: java, hibernate, unit-testing

I am trying to use an extra test database for my java tests.

I´m using Maven as Build-Management-Tool. As testing FrameWork Junit (Junit 5).

In the test folder in Intellj, I have created an extra resources folder and hibernate.cfg.xml. The connection to the test database is stored in this cfg file:

```
    <!-- Database connection settings -->
    <property name="connection.url">jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/test_database</property>
    <property name="connection.driver_class">com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver</property>
    <property name="connection.username">root</property>
    <property name="connection.password"> </property>

    <!-- SQL dialect -->
    <property name="dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect</property>

    <!-- Echo all executed SQL to stdout -->
    <property name="show_sql">false</property>
    <property name="format_sql">true</property>
    <property name="current_session_context_class">thread</property>

    <!-- Mapping Entity classes -->
    <mapping class="entity.UserEntity"/>
```

Does anyone have experience how to use an extra database for testing? Is there anything I need to consider when using Intellj?

Do you even separate a development database and a test database for testing? Or do you just use one database?

I am still a newbie when it comes to javatests.

If you need more information, let me know.

Comment: I am not entirely sure what you mean. Normally, we use a dedicated database in a well-known state for integration-/e2e-tests. I also fail to see how IntelliJ plays into this. What kind of tests are we talking about? Unit? Acceptance? Integration? E2E? What testing framework(s) are you using? Are you using maven or gradle?

Comment: @Turing85 I have expanded the question with more information. right now it is only about unit tests. i am testing register and login controller.

Comment: Honestly, for unit test I would mock the persistence layer if possible, thus not hitting the "real" database. Alternatively, we can use an in-memory H2 datababse. But we should keep in mind that H2 may behave differently from, for example, a MySQL- or popstgres-database. In particular, it may throw different exceptions with different messages.

Comment: Okay, I think, i will try to mock the persistens layer. Thank u!

Comment: For getting clean separate database for every test you could use https://www.testcontainers.org/.